# Как передать переменные из сессии в базу данных

Tags: php, pdo

Допустим, такой метод у меня не прокатывает:

```
session_start ();
$name=htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]);
$password=htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]);
$_SESSION["name"]=$name;
$_SESSION["password"]=$name;
$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "myBase");
    $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO 'users'('login', 'password','reg_date') VALUES('$login'," '.md5($password)." ', '".time()." ')");
    $mysqli->close();
```

Кавычки, точки уже по разному лепил. В phpMyAdmin на денвере увидел шаблон когда пробовал добавить вручную, там предлагалось заключать в скобки `[ ]`, но это тоже не помогло. То что данные могут передаваться не в `utf8` имеет место?

P.S. Как и прежде гуглить походу не умею. Но есть же это замечательное соо.

Comment: C гуглением я вам помогу - [читайте](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 2):

У вас ошибка в коде.Имена баз,таблиц и колонок надо заключать в обратные кавычки.

Надо вам было заменить

```
'users' на `users`,
```

а вот строковые значения заключать в обыкновенные кавычки.И при правильной конкатенации будет вам успех.Посмотрите например там все поймете.Кстати он должен сработать.Поменяйте вашу строку на эту.

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `users`(`login`, `password`,`reg_date`) VALUES('".$login."','".md5($password)."', '".time()."')");
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное...

Comment: @OTBET_CEPBEPA  всегда пожалуйста:).Если вы считаете что данный ответ исчерпывающий то попросил бы вас поставить галочку возле ответа.Спасибо